# can a module introduce paragraph types and templates?

Tags: 9, paragraphs

I'm building a very complicated paragraph layout with multiple levels of interconnecting paragraph types. At the moment, configuration and template files are all over the place.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to do the same using a module so, it will have all packaged up in one place.

Is there a way that a module to introduce a paragraph type?

Only things I've found so far was a module creating from paragraph types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything will be stored in Drupal's configuration management. So you could add the relevant configuration into your */config/install* folder of your module. When your module is first installed the configuration will be imported onto the site.

Anything else you might need to do in `hook_install()`, such as altering existing configuration, for example user permissions, which cannot be overridden this from your module.

[Include default configuration in your Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-modules/include-default-configuration-in-your-drupal-module) is relevant for you.

In terms of templates, that's fairly straight forward and a module can define its own templates using `hook_theme()`. There are plenty of examples and documentation.

Comment: Thanks @unusedspoon that is exactly what I was after, works like a dream! :)